# Foundation flexbox issue using scss

Tags: sass, flexbox, zurb-foundation

```
.test {
  @include flex-grid-row();
  .eight { @include flex-grid-column(8); }
  .four { @include flex-grid-column(4); }
}



 <div class="test">
    <div class="eight" style="background: red; height: 150px;"></div>
    <div class="four" style="background: blue; height: 150px;"></div>
 </div>
```

Given the above code why does the grid stack and not display side by side? if I remove the 4 from `flex-grid-column()` then is displays as I would expect as the `.four` takes up all the available space, but why not if I specify how many columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After importing Foundation via npm `@import "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss";` I then needed to `@include foundation-everything(true);` Passing true switches to flexbox.

I found that out on this page http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flexbox.html#enabling-flexbox-mode

Answer (score 1):

The markup looks correct and works great in my flex project.
[image: results]
You can make sure you have the flex-grid setup in app.scss

[[image]]
and

Comment: The problem is I install using npm and link to the resources:

Comment: Sorry, was supposed to say I link to it in node_modules so I can manage dependancies. I can't see a way switch grids using it in this way?